# Open file where directory path and file name change in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to open a file if you know most of the directory, but have one folder that changes based on the id of the file in the database and the name of file file is based on what the user names the file.  For example, in the code below id will changed based on the id of the file in the database and the folder name will changed based on what the user names it.  In my case the extension of the file can change as well.

```
File.open("/public/emails/:id/:filename")
```

Comment: like this `File.open("/public/emails/#{id}/#{filename}")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that your `File` model store all this metadata. Then it's a simple case of string interpolation:

```
file = File.find(...)
File.open("/public/emails/#{file.id}/#{file.name}.#{file.extension}")
```

This does of course leave you open to injection-style attacks — e.g., if the user names their file `../../../../boot/grub.conf` or something — but that's application-specific and up to you to implement.

Comment: Thank you.  Thats what I was looking for.  In my case the answer was File.read("public/emails/#{id}/#{email_file_name}")

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem with appending fir and file name to path such as

```
dir = "2" # the name of dir from database entry
filename = "abc"
extension = ".png"
path = "path/dir/#{dir}/#{filename}#{extension}"

File.open(path)
```